# Chapter number to the left, chapter title to the right

Tags: titles, titlesec

Is there an easy way to obtain the following title format:
[image]

I have tried with *titlesec*, but I am not satisfied with my result:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%Chapter Headers%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\Large{\chaptertitlename}\enspace{\thechapter}\filright} {1ex}{\Huge\filleft}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Lorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%Chapter Headers%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\titleline[l]{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]}    {\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
    {\bfseries\filleft}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem}

\end{document}
```